# I have a json file and I want to add new field to it

Tags: node.js, express, fs

I have a json file

```
[{
    "sport": "football",
},
{
    "sport": "swimming",
}]
```

I want to add a new field to each document a uniqueID field which have this form A-11 and increase the number by one for each object

I have tried this in Node

```
const fs = require('fs');
const filenameAppo = './app.json';
const requireFile = require(filenameAppo);

requireFile.uniqueID = 'A-11';
const test = fs.writeFile(filenameAppo,JSON.stringify(requireFile), function(err) {
    if (err) return console.log(err);

});
```

But it didn't work as expected so what is my error in that or if there is another way I can do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the best way to approach this is to create an object wrapper for the file array data, then add the uniqueID property, something like this:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const filenameAppo = './app.json';
const requireFile = require(filenameAppo);

const inputData = requireFile.data || requireFile;
let id = 11;
const output = { 
    data: inputData.map(row => { 
        row.uniqueID = "A-" + (id++);
        return row;
    }) 
}

const outputString = JSON.stringify(output , null, 4);
console.log(`Writing ${outputString.length} bytes to file: ${filenameAppo}...`);
fs.writeFile(filenameAppo, JSON.stringify(output , null, 4), function(err) {
    if (err) { 
        console.error(`An error occurred writing output file: ${filenameAppo}:`, err);
    } else { 
        console.log(`Successfully wrote ${outputString.length} bytes to file: ${filenameAppo}.`)
    }
});
```

You app.json file will then look like so:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "sport": "football",
            "uniqueID": "A-11"
        },
        {
            "sport": "swimming",
            "uniqueID": "A-12"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I want it to be like this
{
    "data": [
        {
            "sport": "football",
             "uniqueID": "A-11"
        },
        {
            "sport": "swimming",
             "uniqueID": "A-12"
        }
    ],
  
}

Because each document must have it's unique id

Comment: Oh yes, I will update my answer, thank you for the response!

Comment: I have tried it so first I call my file on express to launch when the server run like this 

require('../dbDataHolder/init');

and then I use the code you used in the comment but the changes not saved on the file

Comment: Hmmm.. the code may not be running or we might be getting an error, could you try the updated code and see if any of the log messages are being shown?

Comment: It show me this message in  terminal
Successfully wrote 2141 bytes to file: ./test.json.
The problem is that the changes not saved

Comment: That's very strange, we'd normally get an error if we can't access the file. Is it possible some other process is also updating it?

Comment: It access the file and do the changes but it don't save the file with this changes

Comment: Can you try running the script by itself? It seems to be something in your environment that's causing this. If I run the same code the file is saved, perhaps the account the server is running as does not have the rights to update the file?

Comment: Can you share with me how you run the script by it self to be sure we both have the same code running

Comment: I'd normally save as something like test.js, then on the command line do: node  test.js

Comment: Okay this work It looks there is something cause this in the environment I am working at  ,Thanks a lot Terry